# Moment or without, input a string date 'dd/MM/yyyy' and would like a ISO string in output

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I tried followed many articles, but the final ISO string is always with the date wrong:

input: 15/03/2018

output: basing on my timezone, an ISO String

```
c.data.due_date_date = moment(c.data.due_date, "DD-MM-YYYY").toDate();
console.log('ADD TASK toDate', c.data.due_date_date);
c.data.due_date_date = c.data.due_date_date.toDateString();
console.log('ADD TASK toISOString', c.data.due_date_date);
```

in this case the output is 018-03-14T23:00:00.000Z

Any idea?

Comment: Have you tried to change DD-MM-YYYY to DD/MM/YYYY in the first line of your code?

Comment: yep, it doesn't solve

Comment: Can you share a fiddle or a snippet showing your issue? Which version of moment are you using? Anyway `moment('15/03/2018', 'DD/MM/YYYY').toISOString()` should work (See [`moment(String, String)`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/) and [`toISOString()`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/as-iso-string/)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try following this worked for me.

```
moment('inputDate','format').toISOString()
```

Ex:

```
moment('15/03/2018','DD-MM-YYYY').toISOString()
```

Answer (score 1):

This way you can achieve it:

```
var str = "28/12/1994";
var dateStr = str.split("/").reverse().join("-");
var d = new Date(dateStr);
var isoString = d.toISOString();
console.log(isoString); //prints 1994-12-28T00:00:00.000Z
```

Comment: This is working, thanks! But I was also trying to understand if there is the possibility, through angular locales or moment, to output a standard iso string (fixed format on db so output always the same) independently by the timezone and date format in input..

Comment: Sorry, never used moment.As you asked in question moment or without, so i posted this answer.